Algorithms for Simulating Queues
I am trying to simulate a MMK queue (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/c_queue) mathematically.
Currently, I am using the following approach:

Start Current Cycle - Generate arrivals:
The number of arrivals by time t follows a Poisson distribution:
$$ N_a(t) \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda_1 t) $$

Generate arrival times:
For each arrival i, generate an arrival time \$A_i\$:
$$ A_i \sim \text{Uniform}(0, t) \text{ for } i = 1, 2, ..., N_a(t) $$

Generate service times:
For each arrival, generate a service time \$S_i\$:
$$ S_i \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda_2) \text{ for } i = 1, 2, ..., N_a(t) $$

Calculate departures:
The number of departures by time t:
$$ N_d(t) = \max\{n : \sum_{i=1}^n S_{(i)} \leq 3t\} $$
Where \$S_i\$ are the ordered service times.

Calculate waiting times:
For each customer i from \$N_d(t) + 1\$ to \$N_a(t)\$:
$$ W_i = t - A_i $$

Sum the waiting times (this step completes the Current Cycle):
$$ \text{Total Waiting Time} = \sum_{i=N_d(t)+1}^{N_a(t)} W_i $$

Now, we start the new cycle. However, for the start of the new cycle, we repeat Steps 1-6, but after simulating the arrivals for the new cycle , we add the remaining customers from the previous cycle(s) that were not served.


I thought this was a reasonable approach to simulate this queue, but then I tried to implement it and I was getting incorrect results from the simulation (e.g. the queue length was not correct compared to the theoretical answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78961044/simulation-results-not-matching-the-theoretical-answer) . This leads me to think that the mathematical approach I am describing is not entirely correct.
Can someone please comment on if the mathematical approach I outlined is somehow not corresponding to a MMK queue?
Thanks!
